# Is there anyway to have two different setting for cors in Laravel 7.X?

Tags: laravel, cors, cross-browser, laravel-7, quasar-framework

I am wondering if it's possible to have two different cors setting in Laravel 7.X using Fruitcake/Cors library or other methods/middleware.

The reason I need this is that I have a few end-points which is secured using defined domain cors and few end-points which are open (*) because I have a quasar mobile app accessing it.

I tried creating a Laravel middleware for Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

```
$response = $next($request);
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');
return $response;
```

And I am using Fruitcake\Cors for my secured domain-defined cors.

it's working fine if I tried putting either of the global middleware but every time I transferred them to the middleware group the cors are not working anymore.

Here's my kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
//        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
             \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            // Other middleware...
            \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
            'cors.all',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'secured.cors',
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            'throttle:2000,1',
            'bindings',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            'throttle:2000,1',
            'bindings',
        ],

        'fm' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            'throttle:2000,1',
            'bindings',
        ],

        'cfm' => [
            'cirrusfm',
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            'files',
        ],

        'sso' => [
            'cors.all',
            'SingleAuth',
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
        ],

        'cors.all' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
        ],

        'secured.cors' => [
            \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ]
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'portfolio' => \App\Http\Middleware\Portfolio::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
        'fmMobileVr' => \App\Http\Middleware\FMVersionCheck::class,
        'cirrusAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CirrusAdmin::class,
        'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken',
        'jwt.refresh' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken',
        'SingleAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\sso::class,
        'cors.all' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        'secured.cors' => \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];
}
```

I have no idea why it's not working aside from the cors being blocked first before it went to the middleware group.

I hope you can help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your middleware group is loaded on the routes you are calling? try seeing which middlewares are used using php artisan route:list

Comment: it's there, the middlewares are listed on the list. do you have any idea how to debug it? I tried using dd()/var_dump/echo nothing seems to work.

Comment: i can see it's there but it is clearly not working, did you try my command and see the results?

Comment: yes, I tried the command and the middlewares are being recognized, I think the reason why is because the preflight OPTIONS can't get through if I put the cors in middleware group instead of on a global scale.